# Dynamic switching between bound views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS and I am currently trying to figure out how to best approach this functionality:

I am looking for a way where I have something along the lines of `<span editable>I am a text</span>`, and when the user clicks on it, it becomes editable (eg. `<input type="text">`) until the element loses focus, at which point it should flip back to its original `<span editable>...</span>` with the new value. Furthermore, this is likely not static text but bound to a model.

I am thinking this should be doable with directives, but I've hit a road block along the line as to how such a directive would actually work.

```
app.directive('editable', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function () {
            // something.
        });
    }
})
```

Can anyone provide me with guidance or a solution to this?

Thanks in advance,
- Manny

Comment: This may help http://chandermani.blogspot.in/2012/12/angularjs-and-inplace-edit.html

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar, Chandermani. This seems to cover what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer below, I can mark it as a solution, so you get the credit, fame and glory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How i did this was to create a directive that could be applied to any html element. It hides the standard element and shows a text field when you click in it. Then it changes it back to the origninal element when you move away from the field.

More details [here](http://chandermani.blogspot.in/2012/12/angularjs-and-inplace-edit.html)

and here is the companion fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/6gMXL/

You can use it like

```
    <h1>
      <editable model="heading" on-delete="" defaultval="Default val">
    </h1>
```